# How to use if on a specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, if-statement

I want to use an if statement to see if something has hidden written in it. The div classname is ".title-button" and I want to use in javascript or jquery `if {.title-button = "Hidden"){...}` but it doesn't work.

This is for a side project of mine. I have researched it lots of time but I cant find anything

```
if(".title-button" = "hidden"){
}
```

is the only code I have, but it doesn't work.

My expected result is to be able to check the string in the class, I don't get an actual result.

Comment: So there are at least three things wrong with this.  But before that, what is your intention of checking "hidden"?  Are you trying to see if the element is hidden?

Comment: Use [`jQuery#hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/): `if($(".title-button").hasClass("hidden")) {`

Comment: I'm trying to see if the element contains the word "hidden"

Comment: So you're trying to see if `<div class="title-button">hidden</div>` exists?  That's what "contains the word"  would mean

Comment: or if `<div class="title-button">My Button</div>` is visible (actually hidden) at the moment?

Comment: javascript uses double equals for string comparisons

Comment: Yeah, I am. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm trying to see if <div class="title-button">Hidden</div> has the word "Hidden" in it.

Comment: Use `jQuery#text` to get the text content of an element and `==` or `===` to compare it against another string: `if($(".title-button").text() == "hidden") {`. **Note:** You might as well trim the text before using it in case it contains surrounding spaces: `$(...).text().trim()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to check if the element has the **text** of `hidden`, then that would be something like.

```js
if ($('.title-button').text() === 'hidden') {
  console.log('yes');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title-button">hidden</div>
```

There are various issues with your original attempt:

```
if(".title-button" = "hidden"){}
```

## 1) You are not looking up the element

`".title-button"` is just a string.  It's not an element lookup.  To use jQuery to actually look the element up, you have to use `$(".title-button")`.

## 2) `=` is assignment

Assignment is meant to be used with variables (ex. `var x = 3`), not comparison.  Comparisons are performed with `==` or `===`, the second one not performing type coersion.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code says "set the string `.title-button` equal to the string `hidden` and, if that value is truthy (i.e. true, a nonzero number, a nonempty string, etc.), then do something". That makes no sense. So let's take this step-by-step.

"My expected result is to be able to check the string in the class."

What is "the string in the class"? A class name *is* a string, which simply indicates a group that an element belongs to. If you're trying to check whether an element which has the class `title-button` *also has the class `hidden`*, then you'd want to first get the element -- not just its class name -- and check all its classes for the class `hidden`. With jQuery, you can get an element from one of its classes by using `$('.class-name')`, so in this case, `$('.title-button')`. Then you can check if it has a certain class using the `.hasClass('new-class-name`)`method. So`if ($('.title-button').hasClass('hidden')) {` is the condition you want to check.

If instead you're trying to check if the *contents* of the element contain the string "hidden", then you need to first get the contents and then check if it contains what you want. You can do this a few ways, but here's just one: `if ($('.title-button').html().indexOf('hidden') >= 0) {` (For reference, the other methods instead of using indexOf would be `.includes` and `.match`; you could also use `.test`, though that has different syntax since the Regular Expression comes first, so I didn't show it here.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the text "hidden" in the div elements content,for example

```
 <div class="title-button">I am hidden</div>

If(document.querySelector(".title-button").innerHTML.indexOf("hidden") != -1){
    //Your statement goes here
    }
```

If you are trying to find that the div element has class "hidden" in its class list,then there are two scenarios,

1)If you have multiple classes on the div element.For example,

```
<div class="title-button class2 class3"></div>

If(document.querySelector(".title-button").className.indexOf("hidden") != -1){
//Your statement goes here
}
```

2)If you have only one class as follows,

```
<div class="title-button"></div>

If(document.querySelector(".title-button").className == "hidden"){
//Your statement goes here
}
```